# How do i make each movie appear on under their respective date

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i cant seem to make each movie appear under their respective date and have a correct time dropdown menu for the movie time selection

```
$sql_date = "SELECT DISTINCT sDate, sTitle FROM movieScreenings ";
$result_date = mysqli_query($db, $sql_date);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_date)) {

    echo "<h2>" . $row['sDate'] . "</h2>";

    $sql_movie = "SELECT * FROM movieList, movieScreenings WHERE title = '" . $row['sTitle'] . "'";
    $result_movie = mysqli_query($db, $sql_movie);

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_movie)) {


        echo "<div class='box'>

              <img class='poster' src='posters/" . $row2['poster'] . "'/>       

              <h2>" . $row2['title'] . "</h2>

              <p>" . $row2['description'] . "</p>";


        $sql_time = "SELECT DISTINCT sTime FROM movieScreenings WHERE sTitle = '" . $row2['title'] . "' AND sDate = '" . $row['sDate'] . "'";
        $result_time = mysqli_query($db, $sql_time);

        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_time)) {

            echo "<select name='sTime'>

                  <option value='" . $row3['sTime'] . "'>" . $row3['sTime'] . "</option>

                   </select>";

            echo "</div>";

        }

    }

}

mysqli_free_result($result_date);
mysqli_free_result($result_movie);
mysqli_free_result($result_time);
// Close connection
mysqli_close($db);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, I am afraid we need some more info on the data you are using and what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to sort your first query by *sDate* with `ORDER BY sDate`.

In your second query you are again selecting from *movieScreenings* which is not necessary because I imagine all the data you are accessing (*poster, title, description*) is stored in *movieList*.

Thirdly, in your last while loop you are repeating the `<select>` tag for every screening time. This will result in multiple dropdown inputs. Also, you are including the closing `</div>` tag in this loop. So only loop the `<option>` tag.

With these changes your code would look like this:

```
$sql_date = "SELECT DISTINCT sDate, sTitle FROM movieScreenings ORDER BY sDate ASC";
$result_date = mysqli_query($db, $sql_date);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_date)) {
    echo "<h2>" . $row['sDate'] . "</h2>";
    $sql_movie = "SELECT * FROM movieList WHERE title = '" . $row['sTitle'] . "'";
    $result_movie = mysqli_query($db, $sql_movie);

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_movie)) {
        echo "<div class='box'>
              <img class='poster' src='posters/" . $row2['poster'] . "'/>       
              <h2>" . $row2['title'] . "</h2>
              <p>" . $row2['description'] . "</p>";

        $sql_time = "SELECT DISTINCT sTime FROM movieScreenings WHERE sTitle = '" . $row2['title'] . "' AND sDate = '" . $row['sDate'] . "'";
        $result_time = mysqli_query($db, $sql_time);

        echo "<select name='sTime'>";
        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_time)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row3['sTime'] . "'>" . $row3['sTime'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        echo "</div>";
    }
}

...
```

And lastly, I would suggest using ID's as your foreign keys to prevent duplicates in the future. There might be multiple movies with the same title.